# How to Install Internet Explorer on Ubuntu through wine-4.0.1

Tags: 18.04

While installing **Internet Explorer on Ubuntu through wine-4.0.1** i get this [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN2dF.png). Say me some tips to solve this.

Comment: My personal experience says that you won't get desired result by running IE on wine. The best way is installing  a Virtual Machine & run explorer from there.